# How to simplify this easy expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$3\cdot(4x)^2 \cdot 4$

How do I simplify that expression? I know it's easy but I suck at math so a detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Oh and I know the answer, I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: Do you mean $3(4x)^{2\cdot 4}$ or $3(4x)^{2}4$?

Comment: The latter. 3(4x)^2 ... then times 4.

Answer (score 2):

We are given $3(4x)^2 \cdot 4 $, and so here (because we have multiple operations) we must follow the [order of operations](http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html), starting with parentheses. The parentheses in this case can't be simplified further, and so now we move on to exponents: $$ 3\cdot (4c)^2 \cdot 4  = 3 \cdot (4c)(4c) \cdot 4 \  .$$
Here we can take advantage of the fact that [multiplication is associative and communicative](http://www.mathsisfun.com/associative-commutative-distributive.html) by re-arranging the expression: $$\begin{align} 3 \cdot (4c)(4c) \cdot 4 &=3 \cdot 4 \cdot c \cdot 4 \cdot c \cdot 4\\ &= 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot c \cdot c\end {align}$$
and because we know that $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 = 192$ and that $c \cdot c = c^2$ we can say $$3\cdot (4c)^2 \cdot 4 = 192c^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $(ab)^2 = a^2 b^2$, and after using that, it is simply a matter of multiplication, remembering that multiplication is commutative, so $a \cdot b = b\cdot a$:

$$3(4x)^2 \cdot 4 \; = \; 3(4)^2\cdot (x)^2 \cdot 4 \;= \; 3\cdot 16 x^2 \cdot 4 \;= \;192x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

3⋅ $(4x)^2$⋅4
We know that 3 x 4 is 12.
12 x $(4x)^2$
Then we "split" the power of 2.
12 x (16(x^2))
Then 192x^2